# Is diagonalization a sufficiently 'complete' method to prove that $A \not \approx B$

Tags: logic, set-theory

By $A \not \approx B$ I mean both sets have different cardinality. When $B$ is of the form$ \{\bigcup {f_i}\mid f_i:C\mapsto D\}$, by a diagonalization proof that $A \not \approx B$, I mean that we asume that there is a bijection $g:A\mapsto B$ and then construct a $h:A\mapsto B$ based of $g$ (see note $1$.) where for every $i$ and $x$: $h(x)\not = f_i(x)$.

My question is, is diagonalization enough to prove that $A \not \approx B$? More specifically:

1. If $ZF \vdash A \not \approx B$, (by any means), can $ZF$ prove it by diagonalization too?
2. If $ZFC \vdash A \not \approx B$, (by any means), can $ZFC$ prove it by diagonalization too?
3. What if the $A$ and $B$ are not bounded variables by quantifiers? (So 1. and 2. allow for quantifiers and for no-quantifiers, what about just no-quantifiers?) That is, they are specific sets can build them by our axioms.

Intuitively, I thought that it would not be strong enough, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample for either $1.$ or $2.$. And even if I had a counterexample where I didn't know how to use diagonalization, that doesn't imply diagonalization doesn't work, what kind of proof would be needed to rule it out?

---

$1.$ By $h$ constructed on $g$ I mean two properties. First, in the definition of $h$, $f$ is mentioned. Second, you can not replace any sequence of strings containing $f$ from the definition and replacing them by $x=x$ or $x\not =x$ such that this new $h^*$ is equal to the original $h$. This is as to rule out trivial inclusions of $f$ such as $h=def(h) \wedge f(x)=f(x)$; where $def(h)$ is a formula characterizing $h$.

Comment: One can define diagonalization by saying "There is a function $F\colon B^A\to B$ such that $F(f)\notin\operatorname{rng}(f)$". Another way, perhaps a more explicit way, is to say that $F$ itself is definable as well. The former way follows trivially from the axiom of choice, but is not provable without choice, I think (I need to think about this one).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have corrected the characterization.

Comment: @Asaf Thanks for the definition, I have included a different one that required changing $B$ but I hope that it is simpler to work around and rules out arguments that don't really using the diagonalization.

Comment: Asaf's version seems like something one could possibly use, since it just talks about the existence of various sets. Your characterization, otoh, saying there exists a proof that cannot be modified in a certain manner, is going to be very difficult to prove anything about.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The problem with Asaf's version is, as he himself noted, you can get that $F$ by first proving $A\not \approx B$ and then using choice to create it. And I see no way of ruling out choice while still allowing for the full deductive power of ZFC. Simple rules like $F$ is not defined by choice would just  kick the use of choice one step back, like creating an auxiliary $G$ with choice and then defining $F$ in terms of $G$. I don't see a way of avoiding this without limiting choice more than is needed.

Comment: Fine. I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: I am looking for a more constructive (?) formulation of $F$. For example, using the terminology of my question, if $A$, $C$ and $D$ are $\mathbb{R}$ I was looking if an $h$ can always be constructed from $g$ (e.g. by uses of operations on the reals). Not really looking for the existence of an $h$ per se.